# Why these elements do not remove based on index after I click button

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend, web-frontend

<sub>your text</sub>I try to make todo app but when I click delete button it should delete element based on index but it does not delete the first element if I post once, but if I post multiple time then it deletes couple elements and how can I fix this?

[variable for the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI2kw.jpg)

[this is when you add elements in todos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0FyD.jpg)

[and this is for deleting elements after click delbtn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZvs.jpg)

Comment: Please, add your scripts as text not images so we can help you faster.

Comment: it did not allow me to add the code as the text therefore i screenshot them, somehow help me please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Click [edit] then `[<>]`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the calls a little like this:

```
<input class="url" />
<button onclick="addItem()">post</button>
<div class="content"></div>

<script>
  let todos = [];

  const input_value = document.querySelector(".url");

  const postBtn = document.querySelector(".post-btn");

  const content = document.querySelector(".content");


  function addItem() {
    let post = input_value.value;

    todos.push(post);

    renderTodos();
  };

  function renderTodos() {
    content.innerHTML = "";

    todos.map((todo, index) => {
      let html = `<div class="el">
        <p>${todo}</p>

        <button class="del-btn" onclick=deletion('${index}')>DELETE</button>
        </div>
      `;

      content.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    });
  }

  function deletion(key) {
    delete todos[key];

    renderTodos();
  }
</script>
```

You were having problems with rendering after deletion. Your `content.innerHTML = "";` in there was "replacing" the previous todos.